# Simplifying sum of sort

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I want to know that simple method of sqrt sum

I have 10 values of some information. Let these be $d_1 , ... , d_{10}$

And I want to calculate $\frac {\sqrt d_1+...+\sqrt d_{10}}{10}$ in computer (mean value)

But calculation of sqrt is complex in computer

So, is there a simple method to calculate that value with more less use sqrt (i.e. similarity value)?

In fact $d_i$ is the value that square of distant of two points $x_{i-1} , x_i$ in $R^3$

Comment: Why is calculation of sqrt difficult in computer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in which language you are programming, but if it is object oriented, define a class of floats with low precision Lpf and a method Lpf.sqrt(). Implement it to give the precision you need.

It will make a difference only if you use this function millions or billions of times. And still you will have to retouch somehow your code to optimize the function call time.